# Command-line implementation of Mastermind

Tags: beginner, ruby

I just finished this command-line implementation of the Mastermind board game that allows two players to play against each other. I'm fairly new to Ruby, but I think I did a decent job with this. However, I'm sure there are some things I could've done better, so please let me know if there are.

```
class Codebreaker
  attr_accessor :colors

  def initialize
    @colors = []
  end
end
```

```
require 'io/console'

class Codemaker
  attr_accessor :code_colors

  def make_code
    puts "\nCodemaker, select 4 colors! Please enter them separated by spaces, with no commas.  To prevent cheating, your input will be hidden.  Try to not make any typos :)"
    input = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
    @code_colors = input.split(" ")
    puts "Excellent!"
  end
end
```

````
class Game
  require_relative "codebreaker.rb"
  require_relative "codemaker.rb"

  def initialize
    @code_breaker = Codebreaker.new
    @code_maker = Codemaker.new
    @turn = 1
    start_game
  end

  def start_game
    puts "Welcome to Mastermind!
    \nRules: 
    \nThe codemaker creates a code consisting of four colors chosen from the provided list.  
    It is the goal of the codebreaker to crack the code in 12 turns, entering the same exact colors in the same order.  To attempt to crack the code, simply
    keep guessing.  
    \nYou may choose from the following colors: red, blue, green, yellow, orange, purple, white, and black."
    @code_maker.make_code
    turn
  end

  def turn
    while @turn < 12
      code_breaker_input
      compare
      @turn += 1
      if @turn == 12
        puts "Unfortunately, you didn't guess the codemaker's code in the allotted 12 turns.  Better luck next time!"
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  def code_breaker_input
    puts "\nCodebreaker, please make your selection! Enter colors in lowercase, separated by spaces, with no commas."
    @code_breaker.colors = gets.chomp
  end

  def compare
    b_colors = @code_breaker.colors.downcase.split(" ")
    m_colors = @code_maker.code_colors
    correct_indexes = []
    correct_colors = []

    b_colors.zip(m_colors).map { |a, b|
      if a == b
        correct_indexes << "X"
      else correct_indexes << "O"       end
    }

    b_colors.each { |color|
      m_colors.any? { |c_color|
        correct_colors << color if c_color == color
      }
    }

    puts correct_indexes.join(" ")
    puts "Colors guessed correctly: #{correct_colors.join(", ")}"

    #checks win condition
    if correct_indexes.all? { |index| index == "X" }
      puts "The codemaker cracked the code!"
      exit
    end
  end
end

game = Game.new
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple things you can improve:

- `12` is a magic number in your code, you can move it to a constant.
- I think `TURNS.times do |turn| ...` is better than the while loop because you don't have to keep track of the counter.
- When you're passing a simple space (`" "`) to the method `split` you can just call `split` instead, without passing any argument.
- When the block has multiple lines it is a good practice to use `do` and `end` instead of brackets.
- I think you can use the `select` method and assign the result directly to the `correct_colors` variable.
- I think it would be better to call `Game.new.start_game` instead of `Game.new`, for me, it isn't intuitive that the game will begin just by instantiating the `Game` class.
- You can make some methods private because you are not calling them on the instance.